# Is there a standard format to store metadata of a repository?

Tags: git, github, metadata, standards, file-format

Is there a standard method or format to mirror repository metadata?

For example, a Github repository may have specified

- short description
- website
- list of Github tags (displayed below description, see image below)

This data is edited using Github interface and not stored in a git repository.

I want to change it for my projects to keep also this part of my data backuped, reduce Github lockin and make potential migration easier.

I searched for and failed to find any proposed/used format for that data. I prefer to avoid reinventing the wheel, so I am asking here whatever there is any standard way to do that.

To clarify tags: it is not about git tags, but about Github tags. For example https://github.com/openstreetmap/openstreetmap-website has `openstreetmap`, `rails-application` and `ruby` Github tags.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a standard method or format to mirror repository metadata?

There is no. But there are a few widely used conventions.

> short description

Edit `.git/description`. Most self-hosted solutions (I use git-web)
display its content as the description.

> website

Put it into a README file. README.txt or README.md or README.rst.

> list of Github project tags

No, topics are really github-specific, and every other solution implements them in its own way. As a Python programmer I use [`keywords` in setup.py](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0314/#keywords-optional); just an example of how different it could be.

Comment: "This is not a metadata, it's a normal part of any repo" - I now updated question that I ask about Github tags, not about git tags.