# Is there a standard way to store a "commit URL" info in git repository for tools like VS IDE?

Tags: git, visual-studio, ide

Tools (IDEs) that work with git repos may provide shortcuts to open a commit's URL.

[image: A commit's context menu in VS 2022]

However, at least in VS IDE, the shortcut seem to require a GitHub-hosted repo, or maybe something else.

The question is: for a project using an own infra (example: LibreOffice using own-hosted gerrit), is there a way to store some metadata in git repo / config, that would allow tools to know how to construct commits' URLs, like
https://git.libreoffice.org/core/+/2f848eb5dc6f6f9344f250ac9860065130aaf436 for commit `2f848eb5dc6f6f9344f250ac9860065130aaf436`?

Based on this question:

> [Is there a standard format to store metadata of a repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52606923/is-there-a-standard-format-to-store-metadata-of-a-repository)

there seem to be no way *generally*, - but maybe for this specific case, something exists, or maybe there are other ways - like using common (even if not standardized) conventions, or some extensions for specific IDEs?